# Matplotlib subplot using nested for loop to plot timeseries (trajectory)

Tags: matplotlib, nested-loops

I want to plot 5 timetable series using nested for loop. here is my code attached and the results of the plots. I use the first loop to generate each when I put plt.show() outside the first loop, it will just plot the fifth series, and when I put the plt.show() outside the inside (second) loop, it will just plot the first series.

1. How can I plot all five series using the nested loop?
2. How can I plot all of the same y variables with the same bound (shared y) in the loop?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(38, 55))
    for i in range(len(Traj_List)): # first loop for creating subplots for each of timeseries data  (Trajectory of some states like joint angle and joint speed and muscle activations)
        # States.
        stateNames = list(Traj_List[i].getStateNames()) # Traj_List is a list of timeseries data
        numStates = len(stateNames)
        dim = np.sqrt(numStates)
        if dim == np.ceil(dim):
            numRows = int(dim)
            numCols = int(dim)
        else:
            numCols = int(np.min([numStates, 4]))
            numRows = int(np.floor(numStates / 4))
            if not numStates % 4 == 0:
                numRows += 1

        # color = iter(plt.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, 5)))
        color = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'y', 'm']
        lines = ["-", "--", "-.", ":", "-."]
        linewidth = [3, 2.5, 3.5, 2, 3]

        for j in np.arange(numStates): # the second loop plots each time series data (states) against time.
            ax = fig.add_subplot(numRows, numCols, int(j + 1))
            ax.plot(Traj_List[i].getTimeMat(),
                    Traj_List[i].getStateMat(stateNames[j]), linestyle=lines[i], color=color[i],
                    linewidth=linewidth[i], label=Label_List[i])

            stateName = stateNames[j]
            ax.set_title(stateName)
            ax.set_xlabel('time (s)')
            # ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
            ax.legend(loc='best')
            if 'value' in stateName:
                ax.set_ylabel('position (rad)')
            elif 'speed' in stateName:
                ax.set_ylabel('speed (rad/s)')
            elif 'activation' in stateName:
                ax.set_ylabel('activation (-)')
                ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
        # plt.show()

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to only make the figure once, and save the axes.  In pseudo code, because I can't run your code anyway:

```py
for i in range(N):
    M, N = size(data)
    if i == 0:
      # only make the axes once!
      fig, axs = plt.subplots(M, N)
    for j in range(M*N):
       axs.flat[j].plot(yourdata)
```

I'm sure my ranges are not correct for your data, but that is easy to sort out.  The point is don't keep recreating the axes using `plt.add_subplot`.  Just create them once, and then plot on them.